# Dockerfile: How to source Anaconda

Tags: docker, anaconda, dockerfile

I am trying to set up an Anaconda environment with AWS Batch

Here is a snippet from my Dockerfile

```
#: Download Anaconda
COPY Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh /setup/
RUN bash Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /home/ec2-user/anaconda3 
RUN echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin' >>~/.bashrc \
    && /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"
ENV PATH $PATH:/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin

# Create the environment:
COPY environment.yml .
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml

# Make RUN commands use the new environment:
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "solver_env", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
```

When I access my container, and do some simple tests I get an error that

```
conda: command not found
```

Even though I have sourced the path to my bashrc file.

Also when trying to access my bashrc file I get

```
cat ~.bashrc: No such file or directory
```

and

```
cat: //.bashrc: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas on where I may be going wrong/where to check?

EDIT:

Last line in my Dockerfile to activate the venv and kick off the script is:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "-n", "solver_env", "/bin/bash", "/usr/local/bin/fetch_and_run.sh"]
```

Once I have the image built and deployed to AWS ECR, I kick off a Batch job which essentially runs this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
date
echo "Args: $@"
env
echo "script_path: $1"
echo "script_name: $2"
echo "path_prefix: $3"
echo "jobID: $AWS_BATCH_JOB_ID"
echo "jobQueue: $AWS_BATCH_JQ_NAME"
echo "computeEnvironment: $AWS_BATCH_CE_NAME"
   
mkdir /tmp/scripts/
aws s3 cp $1 /tmp/scripts/$2
python3 /tmp/scripts/${@:2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten a slash in your command:

```
cat ~.bashrc: No such file or directory
```

It should be:

```
cat ~/.bashrc
```

Also everything you do with `.bashrc` in your Dockerfile is pointless. Not only, as @Itamar states in his answer is `.bashrc` only executed in [interactive non-login shells](https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file), but every `RUN` command uses its own Bash process and you even use a separate process to source it manually, which essentially means you start Bash, source `.bashrc` and then discard that instance of Bash, discarding all changes with it.

I have answered a similar question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1582294/how-to-run-a-conda-command-inside-singularity) and the solution applies here as well. It's actually simpler, since you want to use the Docker image with Docker and not with Singularity and you want to run is as root.

```
COPY Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh /setup/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh
COPY environment.yml /setup/environment.yml
RUN bash /setup/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /home/ec2-user/anaconda3 && \
    rm /setup/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    ln -s /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/conda /usr/bin/conda && \
    conda env create -f /setup/environment.yml && \
    rm /setup/environment.yml

CMD ["conda", "run", "-n", "solver_env", "/bin/bash"]
```

If you want to run some more conda commands after creating the environment you should append them to the existing `RUN` instruction, like so:

```
COPY Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh /setup/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh
COPY environment.yml /setup/environment.yml
RUN bash /setup/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /home/ec2-user/anaconda3 && \
    rm /setup/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    ln -s /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/conda /usr/bin/conda && \
    conda env create -f /setup/environment.yml && \
    rm /setup/environment.yml && \
    conda run -n solver_env python -V

CMD ["conda", "run", "-n", "solver_env", "/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: I added this to my Dockerfile, but am getting the following error when running my script:  `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/solver_env/.tmp1rt1ypkb'`.

Do I need to add permissions to anaconda at some point within the Dockerfile?

Comment: How are you running the script exactly?

Comment: Ah, just needed to run it as USER=root.

Comment: The main issue now is that my container does not seem to be running the script inside the virtual environment. I install `pandas` within the environment.yml file, but am getting errors when running my application that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' `

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying `SHELL`, you should instead prepend the environment's `bin` directory to `PATH`.

```
COPY Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh /setup/
RUN bash Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /home/ec2-user/anaconda3 
RUN echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin' >>~/.bashrc \
    && /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"
ENV PATH=$PATH:/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin

# Create the environment:
COPY environment.yml .
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml
# Activate the environment.
ENV PATH=/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/solver_env/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

`.bashrc` is only used in interactive shells. Try adding `-i` to the `ENTRYPOINT`, before the `-c`.