# Dockerfile: Cannot access python modules installed in virtual environment

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am setting up a virtualenv for running an application with some python code on AWS Batch.
My Dockerfile basically installs an application, installs Anaconda, sets up a conda environment with some python packages, and then runs a shell script inside my virtual environment.

This last part is where I am having trouble.

My logger tells me that:

```
import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Even though I install pandas within my `environment.yml` file:

```
name: solver_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.7.*
  - pandas
  - numpy
  - ujson
  - pip
  - pip:
     - docplex
     - boto3
     - grpcio
     - grpcio-tools
```

Why is my script not being run within my virtual environment?

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest

# Download packages for container
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum -y install which unzip aws-cli \
RUN yum install -y tar.x86_64 
RUN yum install gzip -y
RUN yum install ncompress -y
RUN yum -y install wget
RUN yum install -y nano
RUN yum install -y python3

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /setup

#: Copy CPLEX installer binary and installation script.
COPY cplex_odee1210.linux-x86-64.bin /setup/
COPY cplex_installer_input.sh /setup/

#: Install CPLEX and update .bashrc
RUN ./cplex_installer_input.sh | bash cplex_odee1210.linux-x86-64.bin
RUN echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Optimizer1210/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux' >>~/.bashrc \
    && /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"
ENV PATH $PATH:/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Optimizer1210/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux

#: Download Anaconda and set up venv
COPY Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh /setup/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh
COPY environment.yml /setup/environment.yml
RUN bash /setup/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /home/ec2-user/anaconda3 && \
    rm /setup/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    ln -s /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/conda /usr/bin/conda && \
    conda env create -f /setup/environment.yml && \
    rm /setup/environment.yml &&\
    conda run -n solver_env python -V

CMD ["conda", "run", "-n", "solver_env", "/bin/bash"]
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "solver_env", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN python -m docplex.mp.environment

#: Temp directory for cplex/python API build
RUN cd /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Optimizer1210/cplex/python/3.7/x86-64_linux/ \
    && mkdir build \
    && env PATH=$PATH python setup.py install --home /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/solver_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages \
    && python -m docplex.mp.environment
    
#script for running python files in aws bagch
ADD fetch_and_run.sh /usr/local/bin/fetch_and_run.sh

# Trying to kick off script within my venv -- which is where things are failing
ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "-n", "solver_env", "/bin/bash", "/usr/local/bin/fetch_and_run.sh"]
```

My `fetch_and_run.sh` basically just kicks off a python script.

Answer (score 0):

Your Dockerfile is a mess.

You have multiple `RUN` instructions one after another, no cleanup after yum, you install 3 different versions of Python (from yum, anaconda default and the one specified in `environment.yml`, you use `ADD` instead of `COPY`, even though you do not need ADD-specific functionality, you mess around with `.bashrc` despite my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63996860/dockerfile-how-to-source-anaconda) explanation that it is pointless.

After cleanup your Dockerfile should look like:

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest

WORKDIR /setup

COPY cplex_odee1210.linux-x86-64.bin /setup/cplex_odee1210.linux-x86-64.bin
COPY cplex_installer_input.sh /setup/cplex_installer_input.sh
COPY Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh /setup/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh
COPY environment.yml /setup/environment.yml
COPY fetch_and_run.sh /run/fetch_and_run.sh

ENV PATH=/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Optimizer1210/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux:$PATH

RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install -y which unzip aws-cli \
    tar.x86_64 \
    gzip \
    ncompress \
    wget \
    nano && \
    yum clean all && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/yum && \
    ./cplex_installer_input.sh | bash cplex_odee1210.linux-x86-64.bin && \
    rm /setup/cplex_odee1210.linux-x86-64.bin && \
    rm /setup/cplex_installer_input.sh && \
    bash /setup/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /home/ec2-user/anaconda3 && \
    rm /setup/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    ln -s /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/conda /usr/bin/conda && \
    conda env create -f /setup/environment.yml && \
    rm /setup/environment.yml

SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "solver_env", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN cd /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Optimizer1210/cplex/python/3.7/x86-64_linux/ && \
    python setup.py install && \
    python -m docplex.mp.environment
   
ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "-n", "solver_env"]
CMD [ "/bin/bash", "/run/fetch_and_run.sh" ]
```

although I can't test it, since I do not currently have access to CPLEX installation scripts.